# Jquery touchstart not working for modal fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

In my angularJs project touchstart event is not working on modal fields (**rate1** in below code) but the non modal fields in the page are working well. Any help would be appreciated.

Please find below my code:

```
<div class="percentage-field">
    <span ng-show="!capEntering1 && addQuteFormPopup.interestRate1.$touched" class="double-digit" ng-if="!fhaCtrl.isDisabled">%</span>
    <input type="text" id="rate1" name="interestRate1" placeholder="XX.XXX %"  ng-class="{'error': addQuteFormPopup.interestRate1.$touched && fhaCtrl.interestRate1 ==='0.0'}" ng-disabled="fhaCtrl.isDisabled" gw-allow-only="numbers dots" number-format="5,3" maxlength="6" ng-model="fhaCtrl.interestRate1"
    class="form-control" ng-blur="capEntering1 = false;" ng-focus="capEntering1 = true"><span class="double-digit" ng-if="fhaCtrl.isDisabled" ng-init="capEntering1 = true">%</span>
</div>
```

Controller code:

```
 angular.element(document).ready((): void => {
    $('#editLoanAmount').on('touchstart', (): void => {
        $('#editLoanAmount').attr('type', 'number');
    });
        $('#editDti').on('touchstart', (): void => {
        $('#editDti').attr('type', 'number');
    });
    $('#rate1').on('touchstart', (): void => {
        $('#rate1').attr('type', 'number');
    });
});
```

Comment: Sorry. forgot to mention that the event's (touchstart) purpose is to update the type attribute to number and as a result display number pad in mobile devices.

editLoanAmount and editDti non modal fields whereas rate1 belongs to modal

Comment: Never mind...It got resolved by adding the touchstart event trigger after the modal is open.